# Binary to Decimal Conversion - Formula?

Tags: c#, binary, decimal

I've been searching a while and haven't gotten anything too useful yet, I'm working on a subnet calculator, and well I have used the decimal to binary which I found here, though, I haven't found a good way to convert binary to decimal.

Note: Remember its FROM binary TO decimal, anyways, im in need of the formula or something like that (meaning calculating it, not the automated one).

What I've understood by reading some other posts that you can somehow get the result by dividing by 10, but I didn't really understand it, so if anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be glad.

Any and all help is very much appreciated guys! :)

Comment: Since you didn't hesitate to ask for code without posting what you've tried, I thought I would mention that _[there's got to be a better way](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+binary+to+decimal&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t)_

Comment: There's a good explanation of the algorithm [here](http://www.helpwithpcs.com/courses/binary-numbers.htm). It should be fairly straight forward to implement in C#.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Doing it without LINQ:

```
var s = "101011";    // my binary "number" as a string
var dec = 0;
for( int i=0; i<s.Length; i++ ) {
  // we start with the least significant digit, and work our way to the left
  if( s[s.Length-i-1] == '0' ) continue;
  dec += (int)Math.Pow( 2, i );
}
```

A number in any base can be thought of as the sum of its digits multiplied by their place value.  For example, the decimal number 3906 can be written as:

```
3*1000 + 9*100 + 0*10 + 6*1
```

The place values are simply powers of ten:

```
3*10^3 + 9*10^2 + 0*10^1 + 6*10^0
```

(Remember that any number taken to the power of zero is 1.)

Binary works exactly the same way, except the base is 2, not 10.  For example, the binary number 101011 can be written as:

```
1*2^5 + 0*2^4 + 1*2^3 + 0*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 1*2^0
```

I hope that gives you a better understanding of binary numbers and how to convert them.

On a practical note, the best solution is Matt Grande's; it's always preferable to use a library method instead of rolling your own (unless you have a very good reason to do so).

Comment: http://www.binaryhexadecimal.com/conversion/binary-to-decimal-converter

Comment: I had to work on a ternary number system and your explanation saved my day.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful, @Neo!

Answer (score 13):

You can do it like this:

```
string bin = "10010101010101";
long l = Convert.ToInt64(bin,2);
```

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for answer --
Im sorry if i didnt make it clear enough, i meant a way to calculate it, a formula of a kind, not a library/automated way.

Comment: @balls Is this homework?  Homework questions are welcome, but please use the **homework** tag if that is the case.

Comment: @balls Why is the non-library approach a requirement?  I think explaining that would help everyone.

Comment: @cadrell0 This is not homework,  though i can see why it may seem like it ;). Anyways i know i'm pretty new to this so my knowledge is pretty limited. Right now i'm using .Substring to isolate each value and then making an if that adds them up, what do you think? :P

Comment: @balls any answer posted here will be a variation of that basic idea.

Comment: @DJQuimby It's not really a requirement, i'd just like to know if it was possible, it would help me whenever i was working on another language, if there is a formula that is. More than that i'm curious.

Answer (score 4):

11010101 = **1***2^*7* + **1***2^*6* + **0***2^*5* + **1***2^*4* + **0***2^*3* + **1***2^*2* + **0***2^*1* + **1***2^*0*

.................= 128 + 64 + 0 + 16 + 0 + 4 + 0 + 1

Answer (score 4):

This works fine

```
using System;

class BinaryToDecimal
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double sum = 0;
        int n = 1111111; // binary number
        int strn = n.ToString().Length; //how many digits has my number
        for (int i = 0; i < strn; i++)
        {
            int lastDigit = n % 10; // get the last digit
            sum = sum + lastDigit * (Math.Pow(2, i));
            n = n / 10; //remove the last digit
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty straightforward. Let's assume you have `x` as a binary number:

```
string x = "10010101010101";
```

Since we know that the general formula to calculate is, starting from right, `2^index_1 + 2^index_2 + 2^index_n`
we can use LINQ to do something like (not tested):

```
x.Reverse()
 .Select((element, i) => new { Index = i, Element = char.GetNumericValue(element) })
 .Where(a => a.Element != 0)
 .Aggregate(0.0, (a, b) => a + (Math.Pow(2, b.Index)));
```

Comment: I would argue that this is a case where Linq is not the best choice.  That solution is clear as mud.

Answer (score 0):

```
//a is an integer array which has binary value 
sum = 0;
Array.Reverse(a);
for (int j = 0; j < a.Length;j++)
{
   if (a[j] == 1)
sum = sum + (Math.Pow(2, j));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine..

```
private string binary2DecimalCal(string bin)
    {
        string res;
        char[] cArr = bin.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(cArr); // Reverse binary string
        List<string> sArr = new List<string>();
        for (int i = bin.Length - 1; i > -1; i--) // Get the bits
            sArr.Add(cArr[i].ToString()+"x2^"+i.ToString()); // Calculation step for each bits
        res = String.Join(" + ", sArr.ToArray()); // Join the string with +
        return res;
    }
```