# trouble converting binary into its decimal equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, binary, decimal, console-application

I'm currently experiencing a major difficulty trying to get my program to convert binary numbers into their proper decimal equivalent. With what I have it gives me  the proper amount for some numbers like 111=7, but it gives me the wrong amount like 1101 = 11 when it is supposed to be 13.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int num;
            //int n;



            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
             num = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            //n = num;

            bintonum(num);
        }


        public static void bintonum (int num)
        {
            int dig;
            double sum = 0;


                while (num > 0)
                {

                dig = num % 10; //takes the number and breaks it down into each digit
                sum = dig + (sum * 2); //reverses the number and adds the digit aquired from the previous line
                num = num / 10; // reduces the number by one digit to get to zero

                }

                Console.WriteLine("{0}", sum);

        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a school project in which you are not allowed to use the built in functions?

Comment: Do you need to write your own conversion algorithm? As @zimdanen answered below, this functionality is built into the .NET framework.

Comment: If you can use zimdanen's answer, great! If you need the formula, try looking at [this SO question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742777/binary-to-decimal-conversion-formula)

Comment: Your code does it backwards, 1011 = 11.

Comment: Ok so  was close, it was just backwards then

Comment: It is a project for school and we cannot use built in functions such as the zimdanen but I think i've found the problem. I needed to add the Math.Pow to this line "sum = sum + dig *Math.Pow(2, count);" and add in a count variable initialized to 0. I have tried this before but it was not giving the desired results, but now it seems to be doing so. Perhaps I may have entered the variables in the wrong order

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is provided by the .NET framework:

```
Convert.ToInt32(num, 2)
```

Here, `num` is the string, and `2` is the base in which the string is represented.

More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to go from base 2 (binary) to base 10 (decimal), you can use this approach:
111<sub>2</sub> = **1***2^2 + **1***2^1 + **1***2^0
...... = 4 + 2 + 1 = 7<sub>10</sub>

1101<sub>2</sub> = **1***2^3 + **1***2^2 + **0***2^1 + **1***2^0
........ = 8 + 4 + 0 + 1 = 13<sub>10</sub>

The basic premise is that there are two digits for the binary system and every place holder in a binary number can be multiplied by a power of two to get its decimal equivalent. The same goes for places in a decimal number:
121<sub>10</sub> = **1***10^2 + **2***10^1 + **1***10^0
......... = 100 + 20 + 1 = 121<sub>10</sub>

2543<sub>10</sub> = **2***10^3 + **5***10^2 + **4***10^1 + **3***10^0
........... = 2000 + 500 + 40 + 3 = 2543<sub>10</sub>

Also, you can use this approach for any base to base 10 (decimal). Hexadecimal looks like this:
**0** = 0, **1** = 1, **2** = 2, **3** = 3, **4** = 4, **5** = 5, **6** = 6, **7** = 7, **8** = 8,
**9** = 9, **A** = 10, **B** = 11, **C** = 12, **D** = 13, **E** = 14, **F** = 15

1A3C<sub>16</sub> = **1***16^3 + **10***16^2 + **3***16^1 + **12***16^0
............ = 4096 + 2560 + 48 + 12 = 6716<sub>10</sub>

Here is an octal example:
The octal number system ranges from 0-7 and is often used for representing groups of three of binary numbers.
722<sub>8</sub> = **7***8^2 + **2***8^1 + **2***8^0
........ = 448 + 16 + 2 = 466<sub>10</sub>

Answer (score 0):

as you're checking right 'bit' (or 0th bit), you need another loop, check:

```
        int num = 1101;
        int sum = 0;
        int n2 = 1;
        while (num > 0)
        {

            int dig = num % 10;
            sum = dig*n2 + sum;
            num = num / 10;
            n2 = n2 * 2;

        }
```